# How to enable labels and contours for various layers (geoJson) in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, label, maps, contour

I'm writing a web-viewer with Leaflet using multiple layers (some with Tiles and some with geosjson contours) that I had processed using GDAL.
I'd like to display a label with the value of the contour when I activate the respective layer, and disable it when it is not visible. The same with all contour layers. I have tried this code but the labels are displayed at load, without hiding if I deactivate the layer.

```
L.geoJson(mydataset, 
{onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    var label = L.marker(layer.getBounds().getCenter(), {
      icon: L.divIcon({
        className: 'label',
        html: feature.properties.MY_VARIABLE,
        iconSize: [100, 40]
      })
    }).addTo(map);
  }
});
```

I know that `}).addTo(map)` could be the cause of that. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Add the markers to a `L.LayerGroup and leverage that. It should be even possible to reuse the `L.GeoJSON` for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good clue to do.